# How can I select expressions that cannot be a member of a group and are not empty in regex for markdown?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to do a customized markdown. I am also using katex with the `$ ... $` group. But when replacing expressions, if they are in the `$ ... $` group, I have to not replace these expressions.

EXAMPLE : Lorem `**Ipsum**`(1) is `*simply*`(2) dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, `$ \sqrt{2} **must be no bold **(3) *must be no italic *(4) $` ****(5) **(6)...

- Example (1): Start with `**` and end with `**` and it's not in a `$...$` group so it will be bold.
- Example (2): Start with `*` and end with `*` and it's not in a `$...$` group so it will be italic.
- Example (3): Start with `**` and end with `**` but it's in a `$...$` group so it will not be bold.
- Example (4): Start with `*` and end with `*` but it's in a `$...$` group so it will not be italic.
- Example (5): Start with `**` and end with `**` but it's empty so it will not be bold.
- Example (6): Start with `*` and end with `*` but it's empty so it will not be italic.

So, I need two regex. One of them should select those that start with `**` and end with `**` that cannot be empty and are not in the `$ ... $` group. The other is to select the ones that start with `*` and end with `*` that cannot be empty and are not in the `$ ... $` group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To select the ones that start with `*` and end with `*` that cannot be empty and are not in the `$ ... $` group:

You may use this regex:

```sh
(?<!\*)\*[^*\s]+\*(?!\*)(?=(?:(?:[^$]*\$){2})*[^$]*$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hQdXhi/4)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\*)`: Negative lookbehind to fail the match if previous character is a `*`
- `\*`: Match opening `*`
- `[^*\s]+`: Match 1+ of any character that is not a `*` and not a whitespace
- `\*`: Match closing `*`
- `(?!\*)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if next character is a `*`
- `(?=(?:(?:[^$]*\$){2})*[^$]*$)`: Lookahead to assert 0 or more pair of `$..$` ahead to make sure we are not matching inside `$...$`

---

If you want to match single star text **inside** the `$...$` use:

```sh
(?<!\*)\*[^*\s]+\*(?!\*)(?!(?:(?:[^$]*\$){2})*[^$]*$)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/hQdXhi/5)

Comment: There was only one problem with the `*` inside the `$ .. $` group, it was matching * outside. I did the place with `[^*]+`  `[^*\$]+`, it is all right, but I'm not sure if I did it right.

Comment: Yes `[^*\$]+` is good, I will modify my answer

Comment: I want to add `\`\`\`... \`\`\`` `\`... \`` groups too. Do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: You mean you want to match text between single `\``s outside the `$...$` block?

Comment: `(?<!\*)\*[^*\s]+\*(?!\*)(?=(?:(?:[^$]*\$){2})*[^$]*$)` This regex has $ .... $ but I want to add it to single ` and triple ` groups. Is this possible? I have been trying to add it for about 3 hours, but I could not succeed. I owe a lot to you.

Comment: [Check this for single `\``](https://regex101.com/r/hQdXhi/6) But for 3 `\`\`\`` it will be very difficult.